# Implementing a Stack: Pushed Characters are null in stack

Tags: java, stack

Trying to learn to use stacks. What is wrong with my push method?

```
        input = kbd.next();
        // pushes individual characters onto the stack
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {

            Character ch = input.charAt(i);
            stack.push(ch);
```

---

```
 public void push (T element)
 {
   //System.out.print("\n");
   // System.out.print(element);



   if (size() == stack.length) {
       expandCapacity();}

       stack[top] = element;
       top++;
```

My push method in the Stack use generics so I am wondering why the Characters do not go in. Also tested with strings. I am thinking that this is something specific about Java rather than me not coding the push() method correctly.

Comment: What exception are you getting? stacktrace?

Comment: @AniketThakur he/she clearly said the problem was that the stack filled with nulls, not that an exception was thrown.

Comment: none. Just debugging with print statements. I put print statement right before the line in the push() method and everything is working except that the 6 array elements that are supposed to hold my name hold null values. Thank you for the replies.

Comment: @user3102978 What did you find out by stepping through this with a debugger?

Comment: use print statement one more time, use print before pushing the character in stack , and lets see the character is not null

Comment: I prefer using print statements because i dont know how to use the debugger well. What is annoying about this is that my code is iterating perfectly and my print statements show a null for each letter that is just disappearing into thin air.

Comment: In that case check your `input`. Is it the correct String?

Comment: it appears that my line stack.push(ch) is the one pushing nulls. why is this.

Comment: We have no way of knowing without providing the code for `stack.push()`.

Comment: @user3102978 - It is very important that you learn to use a debugger well, as soon as you possibly can.  It's an immensely powerful tool.  Over your career as a programmer, it will save you _years_ of your life.

Comment: I changed my post. Maybe now you can see why its broken and making the perfect number of nulls for the Character objects I try to put in it.

Comment: Show us all of your ArrayStack class. In particular I'm interested in your expandCapacity method and also whatever you are using to retrieve from it (usually called 'pop').

Comment: there. i posted it in origional

Answer (score 0):

The Possible reason is that the input with string is not Accessible to the method, to resolve , you can use two methods(may be any other).

1)

Write  input=kbd.next(); in side the method;

```
  public void charToStack() { 
 input = kbd.next();

for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {

      Character ch = input.charAt(i); 
      stack.push(ch);


}
```

}

2)    Pass the value of input to the method after getting the input from keyBoard

```
  public void charToStack(String input) { 

  for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {

   Character ch = input.charAt(i); 
   stack.push(ch);


}
```

Comment: anyone else care to give some input?